# How do I substract two objects using a template function?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

Say I have:

```
template <typename T>

T resta(T a, T b) {

    return(a-b);
}
```

This is a template that substracts any given two type of parameters of type T.

And say I have a class Person

```
class Person {

    public:

    int age;

    Person(int ag) {
        age = ag;
    }

    friend int operator-(Person a, Person b) {

        return (a.age - b.age);
    }

    //friend resta(a, b);

};
```

And I have in main:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int a = 5, b=3;

    cout << "Ejemplo de plantilla es:\t" << resta(a, b) <<endl;

    double d1 = 232.23, d2 = 231.4;

    cout << "Ejemplo de plantilla es:\t" << resta(d1, d2) <<endl;

    Person per1(40), per2(35);

    cout << "Ejemplo de plantilla es:\t" << resta(per1, per2) <<endl;  //IT FAILS HERE

}
```

How can I make it possible so that I can use the template function to substract two objects of type Person, and get the age different of the two objects (Of Type Person?)

Thank you.

Comment: Surely *subtracts*...

Answer (score 2):

In C++11

```
template<class T> auto resta(T a, T b) -> decltype(a-b)
{
     return a-b;
}
```

In C++14

```
template <class T> auto resta(T a, T b)
{
  return a - b;
}
```

Comment: and in C++14 you can even omit `-> decltype(a-b)`.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get the `template` function `resta()` for anything.  You've made:

```
friend int operator-(Person a, Person b);
```

you'll get that for :

```
Person a; //...
Person b; //...
int diff = a - b;
```

which is probably what you want anyway.

Comment: No, I want to use the generic template to substract anything (doubles, ints, Persons, future classes, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Class Person needs to be changed to

```
class Person {

    public:

    int age;

    Person(int ag) {
        age = ag;
    }

   friend int resta(Person a, Person b);
    int operator-(Person b) {
        int result = resta(this->age, b.age);
        return result;
    }


    //friend resta(a, b);

};
```

and in main just call the overloaded operator...

```
cout << "Ejemplo de plantilla es:\t" << (per1 - per2) <<endl;
```